# ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “for loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode” GCC error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881/how-do-i-fix-for-loop-initial-declaration-used-outside-c99-mode-gcc-error)

Why must I declare a loop variable outside of the for loop statement?  I am getting a gcc (MacOSX) error which reads:

error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode

If I define my loop variable outside of the loop statement then gcc stops complaining.

Comment: Because, in ANSI C and C89, variables could be declared only at file scope or at the beginning of a block. C99 introduced declaration of variables inside a `for` loop clause.

Comment: Consider using Clang instead of GCC on Mac OS X. Apple won’t update GCC in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Exact duplicate of the question that Chuck linked to.  That said, just set -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 and you're all set.

Comment: I did search for older questions but missed them for some reason.  Next time I will do a deep search.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the error suggests, this is because declaring a variable inside the condition of a for-loop wasn't allowed until C99, and you are using an older language standard. If you're compiling directly, use the `-std=c99` flag. In Xcode, go to the "Compiler - Language" options for your target and set the Language Standard to either C99 or GNU99.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile with the option `-std=c99`.

For example:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 code.c
```