# for loop initial declaration error

Tags: c

In my code I can't initialize variables in for loop initialization part.
When I write this code:

```
    long unsigned int arr[3][3];
char str[50];
for(;gets(str);)
{
    int temp=0;
    for(int i,j,k=0; str[k]!='\0'; k++){ if(str[k]!=' ')temp=temp*10+(str[k]-48);
```

the compiler shows

```
error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in c99 mode
```

I have no idea what that means,
but if I write my code like this:

```
    long unsigned int arr[3][3];
char str[50];
for(;gets(str);)
{
    int temp=0;
    int i,j,k=0;
    for(; str[k]!='\0'; k++){ if(str[k]!=' ')temp=temp*10+(str[k]-48);
```

it works fine.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling in C++?

Comment: add compiler option -std=c99

Comment: You are not in a C99-variant mode.

Comment: actually it written in C...not C++

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881/how-do-i-fix-for-loop-initial-declaration-used-outside-c99-mode-gcc-error/24888#24888) could help !

Try to google it yourself :)

Comment: `for(;gets(str);)`: Two problems. First, if the first and third expressions in a `for` loop are empty, a `while` loop is clearer. Second, ***never*** use the `gets()` function. It cannot be used safely, and as of 2011 has been removed from the C language.

Comment: @Anklon: Please don't use the C++ tag for C code.

Comment: @keith: I'm trying this code in C++ now...
what should I use instead of gets() to take a full string as input.I tried to use cin>> but it seems that it stop taking input when gets any space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declaring variables in loops like

```
for (int i = 0; ...; ...)
```

was new in the C99 standard, and wasn't allowed in the earlier standards. What the error message tells you is that your compiler is set up to compile using an earlier standard, and so you can't use declarations inside `for` statements.

You either have to remove the declaration from inside the `for` statement, or tell the compiler to use a later standard when compiling. Telling the compiler to use a later version can be done by adding the flag `-std=c99` if you have GCC or clang.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a compiler that only supports C89, or the compiler is in the mode that supports C89 only. The declarations of variables must in the beginning of a block in C89. It's not a limit anymore in C99 or C++.

Change to C99 mode or put the declaration of `i`,`j`,`k` in the beginning of the block. The way you initialize them looks incorrect, you only initialized `k`.

```
for(;gets(str);)
{
    int temp=0;
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0,j=0,k=0; str[k]!='\0'; k++){ if(str[k]!=' ')temp=temp*10+(str[k]-48);
```

And don't use `gets`, it's dangerous, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: don't 'fgets()' used for reading from file??
how can I use that in this??

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your former code does not obey the C standard under which you compile the code. Check the manual of your C (or C++) compiler how to turn on (if possible) the compilation under the C99 standard. For GNU compiler it is `-std=c99` switch.