# Converting this code line to C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, arraylist, c99

I have the following code line:

```
for ( int i = index; i < al->size; ++i )

//i,index and size are integers.al is an arraylist
```

When I compile this in C, I get the error:

```
 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
```

Im not sure on how to fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881/how-do-i-fix-for-loop-initial-declaration-used-outside-c99-mode-gcc-error

Comment: Are you using GCC? If so, add `-std=c99` to your command line and that should do the trick. Otherwise just google `<your compiler name> c99 mode`.

Comment: @Olaf You can keep the final last word, good night.

Comment: Your compiler exactly tells you what the problem is. How about just searching for the message?

Comment: @thepirat000: While it seems to be the same, most answers concentrate on changing the code instead of just using a newer standard version. This was ridiculous when that question was asked and is even more ~7 years later with the next standard version already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either declare the iterator outside of the loop:

```
int i;

for (i = index; i < al->size; ++i) {
    do_foo();
}
```

or if your compiler supports it, compile against the c99 or compatible standard:

```
gcc -std=c99 your_code.c
```

(Note that gnu89/gnu90 is the default (as of 4.8, anyway.))

Comment: The first version will change the scope of `i`, thus is bad advice. Note that gnu11 is default for gcc since 5.1 at least.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `int i` before the loop.

Comment: but int i needs to be equal at index?

Comment: Just declaration (`int i;`) outside is required.

Comment: This is bad advice, because it will change the scope. And it is valid C.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the i variable first.

```
int i;
for ( i = index; i < al->size; ++i )
```

Comment: This is bad advice, because it will change the scope. And it is valid C.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int i = index; i < al->size; ++i )
```

needs to become

```
int i;

for (i = index; i < al->size; ++i)
```

Comment: This is bad advice, because it will change the scope. And it is valid C.

Comment: Then what would be the solution? @Olaf

Comment: Use a standard compliant compiler. Standard is C11.

Comment: But if you have a pre-C99 compiler, you have to declare it outside. @Olaf

Comment: See the tags! OP clearly asks about C99. And you neither explaint this in your answer, nor did you make clear that the semantics are different.