# Incompatible "for" loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, c99

I have a C library containing the following function:

```
void arlist_del(struct _arlist *list, int position, int delit) {

if (position > list->size - 1)
    return;
if (list->size == 1) {
    arlist_clear(list);
    return;
}
if (delit)
    free(arlist_get(list, position));
for ( int i = position; i < list->size; ++i ) {  //line were error occur
    if (i == list->size - 1)
        list->data[i] = NULL;
    else
        list->data[i] = list->data[i + 1];
}
void ** new_data = realloc(list->data, arlist_getsizeof(list));
--list->size;
assert(new_data != NULL);
arlist_setdata(list, new_data, list->size, 0);
}
```

However I get the error "'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode" at line identified in code.I wonder how to fix this,I cannot switch to C99 mode.I cant declare "int i = position" in the void line so Im not sure what to do.

Thank you

Comment: declare `int i;` at the beginning of the functions, then `for (i = position;`

Comment: Why can't you switch to C99 mode?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot "int i" inside a C for-loop. You must declare "int i" outside the for loop, then you use for(i = position).

Comment: @Lashane: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: Because im using a editor that doesnt allow it @M.M

Comment: Um wait a minute. This is exactly the same question as your earlier one http://stackoverflow.com/q/33457768/2564301 ...

Comment: You should translate the library as intended: as C99. There is no need to use that for the rest of your code, though. Although it is in general a good idea to use **at least** a standard which is now already over 16 years old.

Comment: This is a different context and code @Jongware

Comment: And: do not post the same question again! YOu already got your answers! @Jongware is correct. This **is** the same question! Or are you going to ask for each occurence of this a new question?

Comment: I am sorry! But I did not realize I had the answer on the other post @Olaf

Comment: Fire and forget, eh? So why then "This is a different context and code @Jongware"? Bad attitude!

Comment: This is true tho @Olaf ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare it outside the for-loop.

```
int i;
for ( i = position; i < list->size; ++i )
```

Comment: Also, in C89, the `int i;` must actually be at the start of a code block. This could either be the existing one, or you could introduce a new block.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in C, originally you had to do for loops like this:

```
int i; // note declaration before loop
for ( i = position; i < list->size; ++i ) {  //line were error
```

You can fix this by making this change in the code, or adding the flag: -std=c99

Also this seems to be a fairly common problem. Please search for your question first before posting next time.

Comment: mixing declarations and statements is also a C99 feature. And OP allready stated he cannot use C99 mode (seems to be some legacy code).

Comment: I thought he meant "I can't" in the sense that he didn't know how, but I see your point.