# Objective C Compiler Errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to objective C.  I am writing code for a coding competition.  For that, I am writing code in my XCode IDE and I upload the code on their website.  The code that works in my machine gives compiler errors on the website.

For e.g. 
A simple assignment of array element which works for me in XCode.

```
NSArray *itemArray;
NSString *feet;
feet = itemArray[0];
```

The above line generates error "incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct NSString *' from type 'struct NSArray'"

I have to use the following syntax to make it work.

```
feet = [itemArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Similary, the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++) {
<#statements#>
}
```

This gives error "for loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode".  I need to make the following change to make it work.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++) {
<#statements#>
}
```

Could anyone please advise how do I configure my XCode IDE so that I can write the code compatible with the compiler in the website?

*Apparently, the supported version of Objective C on the website is GCC 4.4.5  I would like to know whether I can configure it in XCode*

Comment: please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881/how-do-i-fix-for-loop-initial-declaration-used-outside-c99-mode-gcc-error

Comment: Does your Objective-C file end in .m?

Comment: File extension is .m

Comment: @NitinGohel I tried to change "C Language Dialect" in the build settings.  There are options like ANSI C, C89, GNU89, C99 and GNU 99.  ANSI C and C89 gives a lot of compiler errors including errors in header files.  Other options work fine.

Comment: Does it work with GNU99 ?

Comment: It works with GNU99.  I was looking for a setting that would give me compiler error when I try to access array element with syntax itemArray[0]

Comment: Ok...so got the information from the website that the supported version of Objective C is GCC 4.4.5.  Any idea whether I can set it in XCode?

Answer (score 0):

On your first exemple, you are just declaring your variables, but you need to create an instance for you array and fill it with some elements.

```
NSArray *itemArray = @[@"item1-String", @"item2-String"];
NSString *feet = itemArray[0];
```

Otherwise trying to get the first element of the array (with `itemArray[0]` or `[itemArray objectAtIndex:0]` will result in an issue because the array is not instanciated.

Note that if your array is meant tot by dynamic (add/remove elements later), use a `NSMutableArray` type

```
 NSMutableArray *itemArray = [@[@"item1-String", @"item2-String"] mutablecopy];
```

And if you don't know how many items contains your array, check its `count` before trying to get element :

```
NSString *feet;
if (itemArray.count <= 3) { //Is there at least 3 elements? 
    feet = itemArray[2]; //then get third element
}
```

Comment: I left out a lot of code from my post as I just wanted to highlight the problem.    I just want to know why itemArray[0] is giving compiler error.

Comment: What is then the type of the first item in your array ?

Comment: My array contains strings.  It is initialized as

    NSArray *itemArray = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D"];