# Coast length, kattis

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve one problem, which I found on website https://open.kattis.com/problems/coast. Tl;dr version of problem is, that for given map of landscape, I should print out length of coastline (without inner islands).

I receive 0/26 mark, but I have no idea why, I've tested, and as far as i checked, it worked. I assume it doesn't compile, but if that is the case, why is that? It compiles for me perfectly fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int edgeCount(int, int, char*);
int topToBottomCount(int, int, char*);
int leftToRightCount(int, int, char*);
int removingInsides(int, int, char*);

int main()
{
    int n = 0; // number of strings
    int m = 0; // strings lenghts
    //printf("Enter N(number of strings) x M(strings lenght): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &m);

    char coast[1024];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
        scanf("%s", coast+i*m); // adding strings to char coast[1024], making array of ones and zeroes // e.g we are adding 3x4 strings - 111100001111
    }                                                                                                  // it can also be looked as  1111
                                                                                                                            //      0000        - matrix
    int coasts = edgeCount(n, m, coast);                                                                                    //      1111 
    coasts += topToBottomCount(n, m, coast);
    coasts += leftToRightCount(n, m, coast);
    coasts -= removingInsides(n, m, coast);

    printf("%d - coasts\n", coasts);

    return 0;
}

int edgeCount(int n, int m, char *coast){ // if 1 is placed at the edge of the "map", it is 1 coast (2 if it is at corner)
    int edgeCoast = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){     // top edges
        if(coast[i] == '1')
            edgeCoast++;
    }

    for(int i = m*n - m; i < m*n; i++){  // bottom edges (m*n - m = first char in the last string, it can be also looked as the last row in matrix)
        if(coast[i] == '1')
            edgeCoast++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <m*n; i+=m){   // left side edges (first column in matrix)
        if(coast[i] == '1')
            edgeCoast++;
    }

    for(int i = m-1; i < m*n; i+=m){ // right side edges (last column in matrix)
        if(coast[i] == '1')
            edgeCoast++;
    }

    return edgeCoast;
}

int topToBottomCount(int n, int m, char *coast){
    int coasts = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m*n - m; i++){   // we start from first char in "matrix", and move to the (m*n - m = 2nd last "row")
        if(coast[i] ^ coast[i+m])   // we are checking if zero is placed above one or via versa
            coasts++;
    }

    return coasts;
}

int leftToRightCount(int n, int m, char* coast){
    int coasts = 0;
    int p = m-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n*m; i++){       // we start from the first charr, and we are going trough whole matrix, but the last column
        if(i == p){                     // p = m - 1 (last char in first row)
            p+=m;                       // p+=m (last char in next column, and so on)
            continue;                   // we move to next iteration
        }

        if(i == m*n - 1)                //if we are at last char in matrix, we break out from loop
            break;

        if(coast[i] ^ coast[i+1])
            coasts++;
    }

    return coasts;
}

int removingInsides(int n, int m, char* coast){ // Lakes and islands in lakes are not contributing to the sea coast. we are checking if they exist.
    int innerCoasts = 0;
    for(int i = m + 1; i < n*m - m - 1; i ++){
        if( coast[i] == '0' && coast[i] ^ coast[i-1] && coast[i] ^ coast[i+1] && coast[i] ^ coast[i-m] && coast[i] ^ coast[i+m]) // char has to be 0, and to hist left, right, above and under there has to be 1
            innerCoasts++;
    }

    return innerCoasts * 4; // *4 because we added 4 coasts before for each island.
}
```

Comment: This is C code, not C++. Please do not tag spam. Use only the tags that actually apply to your post, and don't just add random ones that seem similar. Tags here have specific meaning and are relevant. If you don't know what language you're coding in, step away from the keyboard until you figure it out.

Comment: Won't happen again

Comment: `char coast[1024];` That cannot satisfy the full requirements: `1≤N,M≤1000`. For example, N=3, M=500 will blow up your code. And you are not taking into account the NUL terminator in each string.

Comment: `printf("%d - coasts\n", coasts);` clearly prints more than just the single integer the problem asks for.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've changed what you said, and now it is 11/26 :D

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling your code using the GCC C++ compiler (4.9.2). It compiled fine and I tested it using the sample problem in [the link you provided](https://open.kattis.com/problems/coast). It spit out the right answer.

However, when I tried compiling using the GCC *C* compiler (also v 4.9.2), it fails with `'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode`, which is explained by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881/how-do-i-fix-for-loop-initial-declaration-used-outside-c99-mode-gcc-error). I think your assignment was graded using a C compiler and the compilation of your program failed due to this error.

Comment: Yeah, I've corrected the foor loop, it works now, but removingInsides function seems to be the prob now, when I have 2 or more islands near eachother, but i'll manage that i guess.
Thanks for the comment