# Error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in c99 mode

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, c89

I've got this problem where I can only compile using the gcc -std=c99 but however, i need it to compile using c89 aka gcc -Wall.  This is part of my code where i use the 'for' loop.  Please see if you can help me out thank you in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[100],i=0,ch;
    int n = 1, sum = 0;
    printf("Check out our selection! \n");
    printf("Airhead - 25 cents\n");
    printf("Fun Dip - 40 cents\n");
    printf("Gummi Bears - 20 cents\n");
    while (n != 0)
    {
        printf("Insert Coins: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        arr[i++] = n;
    }

    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {   sum = sum + arr[j];
    }
......
```

Comment: Define the variable `j` at the start of the function, together with the other variables?

Comment: "*i need it to compile using c89 aka gcc -Wall*" <- these are different thinks. Why do you need this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix "for loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode" GCC error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881/how-do-i-fix-for-loop-initial-declaration-used-outside-c99-mode-gcc-error)

Comment: gcc without a language option compiles for *gnu11* (which is neither c89 nor c99 nor c11). See [the gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html). For c89 you want `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic ...`

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    sum = sum + arr[j];
}
```

You have to initialize `j` in beginning of function.

```
 int main() {
    int j;
    ...
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        sum = sum + arr[j];
    }
}
```