# How to count digits of numbers in C?

Tags: c, loops, count

i've been trying to solve this problem that says to count total digits of numbers, my code is working partially. It works well for the first attempt but in the second, the count adds with previous count. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,x,i,n,count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&num);
        while(num!=0)
        {
            count++;
            num=num/10;
        }
        printf("%d\n",count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to reset `count`.

Comment: You need to reset `count` to `0` before processing each new number.  As it stands, you set it to `0` once, then never again.  So of course it keeps growing.

Comment: @chux OK, I mixed up tabs then....I saw array at that time in some other snippet maybe, and confused that question with this one. Apologies.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has two problems:

- It never resets `count`, and
- It does not treat zero correctly, saying that `0` has zero digits

One of the causes of your first problem is that you do not limit the scope of your variables, declaring all of them upfront. Instead you should declare them in the tightest scope where they are needed: `i` should be declared in the loop header, while `count` should be declared and initialized inside the `for` loop.

As far as treating zero goes, add a special case that prints `1` when zero is entered, or switch to `do` / `while` loop.

Comment: Hello, first of all, i don't know how to use this website well. I hope I am putting this comment at right answer.

When I try to declare 'i' in loop header, it says "for look initial declaration is only allowed in C99 or c11 mode".

And I don't understand your last sentence. my bad english sorry.

Comment: @Maryam_from_wonderland This means that by default your compiler treats the source as some archaic version of C. You need to tell your compiler that you are using a modern version of the language (as in "a version that has been defined 18+ years ago). Here is a link to [how this can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24884/335858).

Answer (score 1):

> the count adds with previous count.

(Re-)set it to `0` before starting (over):

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
  count = 0;
```

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060182/how-to-count-digits-of-numbers-in-c/48060203#comment83092734_48060203) by [*StoryTeller*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller) a cleaner approach would be to define variables in the scope where they are needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n = 0; /* Have it initialised, just in case scanf() fails. */
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    int num = 0; /* Have it initialised, just in case scanf() fails. */
    scanf("%d", &num);

    /* Scope of counting: */
    {
      int count = 0;

      while (num != 0)
      {
        count++;
        num = num / 10;
      }

      printf("%d\n", count);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better yet, limit its scope.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Well yes, makes sense, but it still needs to be (re)-set, initialised then.

Comment: Yes, but I find that limiting the scope as a default by instinct makes these issues... rarer.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I ***completely*** agree! :-)

Comment: i don't whats wrong with my pc. i tried your code, and same result :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `count` to `0` on  each loop.

This code should work fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int num,x,i,n;
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    int count=0; // rest the count on each loop
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while(num!=0)
    {
        count++;
        num=num/10;
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);


 }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't. I put 1 first and then type 1234 and the result is 4. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count decimal numbers you can try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

long count_digits(long number) {
  return number >= 10 ?
    count_digits(number/10) + 1
    : 1;
}

int main()
{
    long num = 123456789;
    long num2 = 1234567891234567888;
    printf("%d\n", count_digits(num));
    printf("%d\n", count_digits(num2));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

`9
19`