# Error in for loop (C language) in Dev C++

Tags: c

I'm having problem in running this code in **Dev C++**.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
    /*
    Write a program to calculate overtime pay of 10 employees.
    Overtime is paid at the rate of Rs. 12.00 per hour for every hour worked above 40 hours. 
    Assume that employees do not work for fractional part of an hour.
    */

    int sal,pay,re;

    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        printf("Write down your over time(in hours):    ");
        scanf("%d",&sal);
        re = sal - 40;
        pay = re * 12;
        printf("Your pay is %d ",pay);
    }

}
```

I'm receiving the following error

> [Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix "for loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode" GCC error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881/how-do-i-fix-for-loop-initial-declaration-used-outside-c99-mode-gcc-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring a variable in the first part of a `for` loop was a feature added to C as part of the C99 standard.  However, most compilers by default use the old C89 standard that don't support this construct.

You need to move the declaration of `i` outside of the `for` loop:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
    ...
```